# Pycharm Jupyter Change to normal table output

Tags: pycharm, jupyter

I am using jupyter notebook inside of pycharm.
I'd like the table outputs to look and work like if I'd use Jupyter Notebook itself.

Instead the tables look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWnRW.png)

It seems like pycharm is processing the jupyter outputs for itself, which is quite annoying.

Thanks

Comment: Is that a pandas dataframe?If so adjust you tafs and question to be more explicit.  You might get more help.  People will complain about the image, but I don't know if you can add a meaningful copy-n-paste..

Comment: @hpaulj usually a table that can be copy-pasted, either as a [CommonMark table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) or in code using whatever native formatting may apply. The screenshots can be invaluable to help understand the exact IDE behavior being talked about, but they aren't by themselves enough to easily reproduce the problem.